# Preview layout with soft keyboard opened

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to preview a layout with the soft keyboard opened in android studio (2.2.2)?

[image]

Comment: Did you create an issue for this with Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Android Studio v2.2.2**

The main feature is When reporting **[Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run)** issues through the IDE, the report now also includes **logcat output for InstantRun** events.

One of the most exciting features of Android Studio is the innovative live layout editing mode that lets you preview an app's user interface across a range of devices .

But Soft Keyboard feature is not present  **v2.2.3** as far as my knowledge .You can create a **[New Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry)** for this .

Check **[Android Studio Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html)**